# Not display all cells TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a tableview with custom cell and I have a problem when I want to add one, when I reload the tableview sometimes, the last cell not display totally.
But when I restart the app, all tableviewcell display correctly. The problem appears most often on iPhone 4S and less often in iPhone 6.
Do you have any idea what I suppose to do ?

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row <= [[[DocumentManager sharedManager] listOfFolder] count]) {
                FolderTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"folderTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

                if (indexPath.row == [[[DocumentManager sharedManager] listOfFolder] count])
                {
                    cell.labelNameFolder.text = [NSLocalizedString(@"mobile", @"") uppercaseString];
//                    cell.labelCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)[thumbsArr count]];
                    cell.tfNameFolder.text = @"";
                    cell.tfNameFolder.enabled = false;

                    cell.labelNameFolder.textColor = kBlackColor;

                    cell.imagePix.image = nil;

                    if ([thumbsArr count] > 0)
                    {
                        cell.imagePix.image = [thumbsArr objectAtIndex:0];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cell.imagePix.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"logoPlaceholder"];
                    }
                    cell.tag = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    NSString *folderName = [[[DocumentManager sharedManager] listOfFolder] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ];

                    NSArray *arrayItems = [[DocumentManager sharedManager] listOfItemsForFolder:folderName];

                    cell.labelNameFolder.text = [folderName uppercaseString];
                    cell.labelNameFolder.textColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                    cell.tfNameFolder.text = [folderName uppercaseString];
                    if ([folderName localizedCompare:NSLocalizedString(@"Non classés", @"")] == NSOrderedSame)
                    {
                        cell.tfNameFolder.enabled = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cell.tfNameFolder.enabled = tableView.editing;
                    }
                    cell.imagePix.image = nil;
                    cell.tfNameFolder.delegate = self;
                    cell.tfNameFolder.tag = indexPath.row ;
                    cell.tag = indexPath.row ;

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
                        NSInteger index = indexPath.row ;
                        UIImage *image = [[[DocumentManager sharedManager] listOfItemsForFolder:folderName] count] > 0 ?

                        [[DocumentManager sharedManager] firstImageOfFolder:folderName]

                        : [UIImage imageNamed:@"logoPlaceholder"];

                        CGSize imageSize = image.size;
                        CGSize viewSize = cell.imagePix.bounds.size; // size in which you want to draw

                        float hfactor = imageSize.width / viewSize.width;
                        float vfactor = imageSize.height / viewSize.height;

                        float factor = fmax(hfactor, vfactor);

                        // Divide the size by the greater of the vertical or horizontal shrinkage factor
                        float newWidth = imageSize.width / factor;
                        float newHeight = imageSize.height / factor;

                        CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0,0, newWidth, newHeight);
                        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newRect.size, NO, 0.0f);

                        //draw
                        [image drawInRect:newRect];

                        //capture resultant image
                        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                                if (cell.tag == index)
                                {
                                    cell.imagePix.image = image;
                                }

                            });
                    });
                }
                return cell;
            }
            else {
                EndTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"endTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                int value = kFolderNumber - (int)[[[DocumentManager sharedManager] listOfFolder] count];
                if (value == 0) {
                    if (WidthDevice < 350)
                        cell.labelTitre.text = NSLocalizedString(@"messageTooEndFolderShort", nil);
                    else
                        cell.labelTitre.text = NSLocalizedString(@"messageTooEndFolder", nil);
                }
                else if (value == 1)
                    cell.labelTitre.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"create %d folder", nil), value];
                else
                    cell.labelTitre.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"create %d folders", nil), value];

                [cell.buttonAchatInApp addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAchatInApp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

                return cell;
            }
    }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
            return ([[[DocumentManager sharedManager] listOfFolder] count] + 2);
    }
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        return 120;
}
```

I had the new cell by this method

```
[[DocumentManager sharedManager] createFolder:self.textField.text];





    - (void)createFolder:(NSString *)folderName
        {
        folderName = [folderName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"_"]; 
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder 
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/Test/%@/%@", [PFUser currentUser].username, folderName]; NSError *error = nil;
        }
```

Comment: did you set the correct frame for tableview?

Comment: Yes because when I restart the app all cells are displaying

Comment: How you add new one?

Comment: @user4263078 Don't post code in the comment. Update your question with any relevant info.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Log `[[[DocumentManager sharedManager] listOfFolder] count]` before and after you add a new object to your `listOfFolder`. It might not get updated at the moment when you are calling `reloadData` on the tableView.